# What to do about somebody spamming the site with posts that don't seem to be Questions but rather a show off?

Tags: discussion, support

Recently somebody is posting their papers on the site in the name of Questions but which doesn't seem so. Rather the papers are (a kind of) show off. Aren't there any policies for such (as we have for Homework and Exercise type question)? Also is there any thing to stop such?

Comment: This is what flags are for

Comment: What form is it in? Actual questions?

Comment: @Peter yes it was in the form of a question (you can check the edit history).

Answer (score 7):

In cases like this, where the post appears to have no value at all besides to promote something, I wouldn't hesitate to flag it as spam. Having a post deleted as spam helps limit the rate at which spammers can continue to spam, and if the penalties turn out not to be warranted, we moderators can later clear the spam flags and remove the penalties.